# Consul: When do events get removed from the event list?

Tags: consul

In consul's [documentation](https://www.consul.io/api/event.html#list-events), it states:
**This endpoint returns the most recent events known by the agent.**

What does it mean exactly by most recent?  Most 100 recent events? 1000? Events fired in the last 7 days?

Is there a way for me to configure this?

My concern is this event list could grow infinitely large if older events are not removed within a reasonable amount of time (which can vary across different applications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging into the source code of consul. I found out it is max `256`

https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/94835a2715892f48ffa9f81a9a32808d544b1ca5/agent/agent.go#L221

```
eventBuf:        make([]*UserEvent, 256),
```

On below you can see the rotation

https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/94835a2715892f48ffa9f81a9a32808d544b1ca5/agent/user_event.go#L229

```
a.eventBuf[idx] = msg
a.eventIndex = (idx + 1) % len(a.eventBuf)
```

Below code shows that the data is pulled from the same buffer only

https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/94835a2715892f48ffa9f81a9a32808d544b1ca5/agent/user_event.go#L235

```
func (a *Agent) UserEvents() []*UserEvent {
```

So you can safely assume, this will be max `256`

Comment: Confirmed with my own code as well. I fired a few thousand events and the events list never went past 256.